# How can I return two char* class variables in one function?

Tags: c++, class, return

I have the following class definition. The `GetName()` function is supposed to return the full name (first and last name), which are `char*`. Someone told me to concatenate them into a global variable and then return it from the function, but I just can't figure out how to do that.

Can someone show me an example please?

```
class bank_Database
{
    int AccountNumber;
    std::string CNP, PhoneNumber;
    char* First_Name[256], Last_Name[256];
    float MoneyBalance;


public:
    bank_Database() {};
    void AddAccount(); //function to create an account 
    void ModifyDetails(); //function to modify name, phone and balance.
    void DisplayAccDetails(); //function to display details
    char* GetName(); //functions to get details
    const std::string Get_PhoneNumber();
    const int Get_AccNumber();
    const std::string Get_CNP();
};
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `char*` or `char[]` for this, but `std::string`. Then it would be just a matter of `return First_Name + " " + Last_Name;`. If you insist on the signature, then you need to allocate a new `char` array inside `GetName` and return that. The caller would then need to delete the array when it is not needed anymore. Using a global variable is a really bad approach, but that isn't much nice either. It would maybe be ok in C, but not C++.

Comment: Possible solution: you can return struct called FullName which contains two arrays as fields.

Comment: You're using `std::string` for other members, why not for `First_Name`, `Last_Name` as well.  I don't understand that??

Comment: Btw. I suspect that your type for the first name is wrong. Instead of `char* First_Name[256], Last_Name[256];` you probably want `char First_Name[256], Last_Name[256];`

Comment: Unless you want to store 256 first and last names then these declaration are incorrect: `char* First_Name[256], Last_Name[256];` Stick with `std::string`.

Comment: Your FirstName member is an array of 256 pointers to type char and your Last_Name member is an array of 256 chars. You're going to have trouble.

Comment: I have no idea why would want to use C-style strings, but if you, for whatever esoteric reasons, are determined to do it, use C strcat() function. This is a bad practice in C++ and you should not do it.

Comment: I don't understand why so many want to find a problem to a solution.  The solution is to use `std::string` throughout -- why introduce a problem by using `char` arrays and `char *`?

Comment: "*Someone told me to concatenate them into a global variable and then return it from the function*" - you were given bad advice, don't follow it.

Answer (score 1):

Return result as

```
std::pair<std::string,std::string> result= std::make_pair(firstname, secondname);
```

Consider also using structured binding to use the result of your function

auto[first,second]=Getname()

If you really need char* that can be returned in pair or you can get from string with c_str function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can return two arrays:

```
auto get() {
  std::array<std::array<char, 256>, 2> names;
  // ...

  return names;
}
```

Alternatively, you can create a name object and return that:

```
struct Name
{
  std::array<char, 256> first;
  std::array<char, 256> last;
};

auto get()
{
  Name name;
  // ...

  return name;
}
```

Finally, you may consider using `std::string` instead of arrays as it is more flexibly.